# Doing a section with one thread and a for-loop with multiple threads

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, openmp

I am using OpenMP and I want to spawn threads such that one thread executes one piece of code and finishes, in parallel with N threads running the iterations of a parallel-for loop.

Execution should be like this:

```
Section A (one thread)       ||      Section B (parallel-for, multiple threads)
         |                   ||        | | | | | | | | | |
         |                   ||        | | | | | | | | | |
         |                   ||        | | | | | | | | | |
         |                   ||        | | | | | | | | | |
         |                   ||        | | | | | | | | | |
         V                   ||        V V V V V V V V V V
```

I cannot just write a parallel-for with a `#pragma omp once` because I do not want the thread that executes section A to execute the for-loop.

I have tried this:

```
#pragma omp parallel sections {
    #pragma omp section
    {
         // Section A
    }

    #pragma omp section
    {
         // Section B;
         #pragma omp parallel for
         for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
             something();
    }
}
```

However, the parallel-for always executes with only one thread (I know because I made the body of the loop print `omp_get_thread_num()` and they are all the same number, either 1 or 0 depending on which thread of the two executed the second parallel section).

I have also tried

```
#pragma omp sections {
    #pragma omp section
    {
         // Section A
    }

    #pragma omp section
    {
         // Section B;
         #pragma omp parallel for
         for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
             something();
    }
}
```

Which allows the for-loop to execute with multiple threads, but it makes the sections non-parallel, and the first section is executed sequentially before the second section.

What I need is a combination of the two approaches, where each iteration of the for-loop and the first section are all run in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested parallelism must be explicitly set, as it is disabled by default in most implementations. Standing to the OpenMP 4.0 standard, you must set the `OMP_NESTED` environment variable:

> The OMP_NESTED environment variable controls nested parallelism by
>   setting the  initial value of the nest-var ICV. The value of this
>   environment variable must be true  or false. If the environment
>   variable is set to true, nested parallelism is enabled; if  set to
>   false, nested parallelism is disabled. The behavior of the program is 
>   implementation defined if the value of OMP_NESTED is neither true nor
>   false.

The following line should work for bash:

```
 export OMP_NESTED=true
```

Futhermore, as noted by @HristoIliev in the comment below, it's very likely that you want to set the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` environment variable to tune performance. Quoting the standard:

> The value of this environment variable must be a list of positive
>   integer values. The  values of the list set the number of threads to
>   use for parallel regions at the  corresponding nested levels.

This means that one should set the value of `OMP_NUM_THREADS` similar to `n,n-1` where `n` is the number of CPU cores. For instance:

```
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=8,7
```

for an 8-core system (example copied from the comment below).

Comment: One should note however, that by default, when nested parallelism is enabled, the nested team will consist of `OMP_NUM_THREADS` threads, therefore one of the threads executing the `for` worksharing construct might timeshare with the the thread executing section A. To prevent this, one should set the value of `OMP_NUM_THREADS` similar to `n,n-1` where `n` is the number of CPU cores, e.g. `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=8,7` for an 8-core system.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following code could do the trick:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = -1; i < x; ++i) {
    if (i==-1) {
        // Section A
    }
    else {
        // Section B
        something();
    }
}
```

But, you need to make sure that x >= 0.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a single parallel region with differentiated activity. e.g.
Nested parallelism should not be needed.

```
#pragma omp_parallel 
{

#pragma omp task  
  once();

#pragma omp for 
  for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
    many(i);
  }

}
```

You could also use explicit if / else based on threadnum in a parallel
region and do the work sharing calculation yourself for the second loop.